# jQuery select an element within a selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using the [multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) plugin for bootstrap.
What the plugin does is take a dropdown(select) and adds checkboxes on every option so you can select more than one option in a select.

The thing I need to do in order to enable the multiselect on a select is just $("#selectThis").multiselect().end()

This is how a select with multiselect looks like in html.

```
select.hidden
.btn-group > button + (ul.multiselect-container > li, li , li)
```

I can add an onChange function like this.

```
        $('#add-workout').find('[name="class1[]"],[name="movement1[]"]')
                .multiselect({onChange:function(element){
                    console.log($(this))
                }})
                .end()
        })
```

**I need to select the .multiselect-container of the changed element but $(this) refers to the multiselect object.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the parent by calling `$(element).parent().parent().siblings(".btn-group").find(".multiselect-container")` instead of `$(this)`, after all you are passing the current selected element as a function parameter ;)